# Matches in 2 subsamples

Tags: probability, bootstrap, matching

So I have a sample of size N.
I make 1 subsample from above sample with size n. (bootstrap sample)
Then I make another one of the same size n.

I wanted to compute the probability of having exactly k matches between these 2 subsamples.
P(M =m) , where M is r.v. for Matches occurred and m from 0 to n.
Also I didn't mention above whether we sample with or without replacement. Assume we do it without replacement in both cases.

All the literature I looked at (birthday problems and so on) is different, since they have N and n to be equal.
Also standard binomial formulas are different from actual simulated results.
Any help  will be great.

Comment: The results are going to vary based on N, n, m, etc. Do you want to narrow this down? Is there any particular set of values that would be representative / sufficiently meaningful for you? I'm just wondering that the full set of relationships might be sufficiently complex as not to be very useful.

Comment: Well say N = 100; n = 50. m runs from 0 to 50. I generally need a full relationship in the desired probability.